# NativeScript Angular: How to make Span tap-able using FormattedString

Tags: html, angular, nativescript

Ive searched for this question but unlucky, I can't get an answer

```
<Label>
      <FormattedString>
        <Span text="Remember: "></Span>
        <Span text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores iure vero dolore temporibus in totam impedit quidem quisquam sed excepturi."></Span>
        <Span text="LEARN MORE" (tap)="learnMore()"></Span>
      </FormattedString>
</Label>
```

How do I do to when tapping on the 3rd `Span` and make a call to `learnMore()`?

Comment: If it doesn't work, meanwhile I would split it to 2 or 3 different Labels

Comment: I want three Span's texts wrap together and can be able to add tap event to each span. Splitting to some labels is not work for me.

Comment: Ok then, I guess you could follow the links in Manoj's comments

Answer (score 1):

Using FlexLayout instead of FormattedString should work

```
 <FlexLayout>
    <Label text="Remember: "></Label>
    <Label text="LEARN MORE" (tap)="learnMore()"></Label>
</FlexLayout>
```

Comment: Its good alternative for simple use case but when you have lengthy text and want to format various parts of text, FlexLayout won't work.

Answer (score 0):

That's still an [open feature request](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3671). Refer the GitHub issue for more details, you will also find work arounds and links to samples there.

Comment: For me, sample is hard to understand, I'm quite new to Angular and Nativescript!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working on NS7

```
<Span
  @linkTap="onLinkTap"
  class="thin-link"
  :text="$t('checkBoxLabel3')"/>
```